# when should i use lambda expressions which comes with C# 3.0?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, lambda

Hai guys,

My fellow developers were talking about lambda expressions this morning. So i decided to ask it here in SO

- when should i use lambda expression
     which comes with C# 3.0?

Comment: A lambada expression?  I thought C# was a modern language, so why does it use such an old dance craze?   (SCNR ;-)

Comment: Don't do any assumptions jae, untill you know what is it and where it is used ;) lambda expressions in C# is great and are something irreplaceable in modern technology like LINQ.

Comment: jae don't confuse lambda and lambada

Comment: funny how people think lambda exps are new and modern.

Comment: @all: before replying to *jae*, you should check the question title how it was before the first edit was applied :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is a general rule when your *should* use them, but if I look to myself I tend to use them whenever I use anonymous methods. Most often this happens when spawning some code in a new thread using the `ThreadPool`, or when doing LINQ queries.

ThreadPool example:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => {
    // the code to run on separate thread goes here
});
```

LINQ:

```
var myItems = GetSomeIEnumerable()
                  .Where(o => o.SomeProperty.Equals("some value"));
                  .OrderBy(o => o.SomeOtherProperty);
```

Answer (score 5):

A lambda expression is an anonymous function that can contain expressions and statements, and can be used to create delegates or expression tree types.

expect of using

```
del myDelegate = delegate(int x){return x*x; };
int j = myDelegate(5); //j = 25
```

you can write

```
del myDelegate = x => x * x;
int j = myDelegate(5); //j = 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: read "[C# in depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988363)" from SO's top-most voted fellow [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). Its an excellent book and you will learn all about the new C# 3 features, especially when to use them, including Lambda expressions.

Answer (score 0):

At least don't use for events á la

```
myUserControl.Loaded += (sender, e) => DoSomething(); // coding horror!!!1 :-P
```

because as of now you still can't unsubscribe and clean up things anymore then so easily. Sure there are WeakEventHandler factories and stuff out there but it's still best to remove all event handlers manually once the UserControl is removed from its parent.

For everything else, I think they do improve readability a lot, so use at own judgement.

Comment: I disagree. I find them especially useful for events. I can see the unsubscription being an issue in only be a few cases.