# Method Within A Method

Tags: c#, methods

I am creating a C# library with some reusable code and was trying to create a method inside a method. I have a method like this:

```
public static void Method1()
{
   // Code
}
```

What I would like to do is this:

```
public static void Method1()
{
   public static void Method2()
   {
   }
   public static void Method3()
   {
   }
}
```

Then I could choose either `Method1.Method2` or `Method1.Method3`. Obviously the compiler isn't happy about this, any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How would a concept of a method inside a method work in C#? The last time I ever saw nested function/method definitions was in PHP and JavaScript, but those were for creating top-level functions on the fly.

Comment: put the two methods in a static class.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: Easy, you can only call it from that method. Delphi supports it.

Comment: @Ray: And you could do *that* via anonymous functions, sort of... but that doesn't tally with "choose either Method1.Method2 or Method1.Method3".

Comment: @JonSkeet yes you could (see my answer). But yeah I'm not sure if he means he wants to call them from outside or not.

Comment: In Delphi you can do it, but nested methods will be 'private' and only the parent method will be able to access to it.  Anyway I miss a lot this delphi/pascal feature to get more clean/organized code.

Comment: FWIW, this is a feature of Pascal, not just of Delphi. It makes sense if some tasks must be repeated several times in the same outer method. It is not the same as anonymous methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create function inside another function in c#,is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047200/how-to-create-function-inside-another-function-in-c-is-it-possible)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: Function in Function possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884319/c-function-in-function-possible)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**This answer was written before C# 7 came out. With C# 7 you *can* write local methods.**

No, you can't do that. You *could* create a nested class:

```
public class ContainingClass
{
    public static class NestedClass
    {
        public static void Method2()
        {
        } 

        public static void Method3()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

You'd then call:

```
ContainingClass.NestedClass.Method2();
```

or

```
ContainingClass.NestedClass.Method3();
```

I *wouldn't* recommend this though. *Usually* it's a bad idea to have public nested types.

Can you tell us more about what you're trying to achieve? There may well be a better approach.

Comment: I was wanting to call a method and then have options about what to do with the code. For example I pass a string argument to the Method, then I could call either of 2 nested methods depending on what I wanted to do with the string, maybe one method would convert to int, the other a double, something like that. Thanks

Comment: @BaliC: I'd probably do that with separate private methods. You *could* use anonymous functions within the public method, but just making them private and documenting the intended use would probably be simpler.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I needed help on, I wasn't sure which way to go about it.

Comment: The example doesn't show the core feature of pascal like nested functions, namely accessing the parents variables from the nested function? Factoring it out to other entities is then useless since you either have to pass everything by params again

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: This question is about nested *types*, not nested *functions*. It sounds like you should probably ask a new question.

Comment: Yup, sorry, probably got confused by the question linking here.

Comment: @AndyJoiner: Yes, indeed you can.

Comment: My mistake - I thought C# 7 was out.

Comment: @Andy: Well it nearly is - but it certainly wasn't in 2011 :)

Comment: C# 7 is out now so basically, Yes you can do this. Go nuts.

Answer (score 103):

If by nested method, you mean a method that is only callable within that method (like in Delphi) you could use delegates.

```
public static void Method1()
{
   var method2 = new Action(() => { /* action body */ } );
   var method3 = new Action(() => { /* action body */ } );

   //call them like normal methods
   method2();
   method3();

   //if you want an argument
   var actionWithArgument = new Action<int>(i => { Console.WriteLine(i); });
   actionWithArgument(5);

   //if you want to return something
   var function = new Func<int, int>(i => { return i++; });
   int test = function(6);
}
```

Comment: handy link for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I Love Delegates Makes Life So Easy... Oh this Should be the answer ..thx

Comment: this solution is a definite way to have nested function in c#.


refer to Wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_function

Comment: This is essentially just created lambda function though isn't it?

Answer (score 62):

Yes, when `C# 7.0` is released, [Local Functions](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/259) will allow you to do that. You will be able to have a method, inside a method as:

```
public int GetName(int userId)
{
    int GetFamilyName(int id)
    {
        return User.FamilyName;
    }
    
    string firstName = User.FirstName;
    var fullName = firstName + GetFamilyName(userId);

    return fullName;
}
```

Note that `public` (and similar modifiers) are not supported [C# programming guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions#local-function-syntax):

> Because all local functions are private, including an access modifier, such as the private keyword, generates compiler error CS0106, "

Comment: that's good to know. is it possible in this example to use the userId value inside the nested GetFamilyName() function without passing it as a parameter?

Comment: @symbiont: Yes, the arguments (and local variables) of the main function are visible to the local one (similar to Delphi). See the second exxample in the image in http://www.infoworld.com/article/3182416/application-development/c-7-in-depth-exploring-local-functions.html

Answer (score 27):

You can define delegates within your method with complete code and call them if you want.

```
public class MyMethods
{
   public void Method1()
   {
     // defining your methods 

     Action method1 = new Action( () => 
      { 
         Console.WriteLine("I am method 1");
         Thread.Sleep(100);
         var b = 3.14;
         Console.WriteLine(b);
      }
     ); 

     Action<int> method2 = new Action<int>( a => 
      { 
         Console.WriteLine("I am method 2");
         Console.WriteLine(a);
      }
     ); 

     Func<int, bool> method3 = new Func<int, bool>( a => 
      { 
         Console.WriteLine("I am a function");
         return a > 10;
      }
     ); 


     // calling your methods

     method1.Invoke();
     method2.Invoke(10);
     method3.Invoke(5);

   }
}
```

There is always an alternative of using a nested class within a class that will not be visible from outside and calling its methods, like:

```
public class SuperClass
{
    internal static class HelperClass
    {
      internal static void Method2() {}
    }

    public void Method1 ()
    {
      HelperClass.Method2();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

As of C# 7.0 you can do that:

```
 public static void SlimShady()
 {
     void Hi([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"Hi! My name is {name}");
     }

     Hi();
 }
```

> This is called **local functions**, that is just what you were looking for.

I took the example from [here](https://asizikov.github.io/2016/04/15/thoughts-on-local-functions/), but further informatin can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) and [here](http://thebillwagner.com/Blog/Item/2016-03-02-C7FeatureProposalLocalFunctions).

Answer (score 4):

Why you don't use classes?

```
public static class Helper
    {
        public static string MethodA()
        {
            return "A";
        }

        public static string MethodA()
        {
            return "A";
        }
    }
```

Now you can acces MethodA via

```
Helper.MethodA();
```

Answer (score 3):

Older thread, but C# does have the concept of nested functions

```
    Func<int> getCalcFunction(int total, bool useAddition)
    {
        int overallValue = 0;
        if (useAddition)
        {
            Func<int> incrementer = new Func<int>(() =>
            {
                overallValue += total;
                return overallValue;
            });
            return incrementer;
        }
        else
        {
            Func<int> decrementer = new Func<int>(() =>
            {
                overallValue -= total;
                return overallValue;
            });
            return decrementer;
        }
    }
    private void CalcTotals()
    {
        Func<int> decrem = getCalcFunction(30, false);
        int a = decrem(); //result = -30
        a = decrem(); //result = -60

        Func<int> increm = getCalcFunction(30, true);
        int b = increm(); //result = 30
        b = increm(); //result = 60
    }
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning when this was added as IIRC this was added recently enough that it might not be available in everyone's environment.  Also `calcArithmatic` might not be the best name for a function that returns a function and does no actual arithmetic.

Comment: I think that's valid on both points. I updated the method name.

Answer (score 1):

Your nearly there

```
public static void Method1()
```

should be

```
public static class Method1{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want to use nested class instead?

That's said, you seem to not respect the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) because you want a single method do more than one thing at a time.

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you just Run a method within another

public void M1()
{
DO STUFF
}

public void M1()
{
DO STUFF
M1();
}

Comment: Not only will that not compile, but it would cause a stack overflow if it did. This is NOT a good idea.